# Is my mac hacked? Found weird things

Tags: mac-mini, logmein

I apologize for posting in length, but I thought being complete would be of more value:

20120822, my browser was not resolving a domain so I went into my terminal to check and lo-and-behold! I find these crazy commands remnant:

```
mac-mini$ su Password:
sh-3.2# sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /etc/hosts
Mar 22 23:07:08 my-Mac-mini.local TextEdit[88957] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _CGSFindSharedWindow: WID -1
Mar 22 23:07:08 my-Mac-mini.local TextEdit[88957] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a     breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
Mar 22 23:07:08 my-Mac-mini.local TextEdit[88957] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument:     CGSSetWindowShadowAndRimParametersWithStretch: Invalid window 0xffffffff
2012-03-22 23:07:19.202 TextEdit[88957:7207] PersistentUI: LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL() failed at inserting URL file://localhost/etc/hosts
```

To make matters worse, I discovered there had been a copy of "logmein" that was deleted. Here is some history:

```
20  /Library/Application\ Support/LogMeIn/uninstaller.command ; exit;    
21  killall Toolkit    
22  "/Library/Application Support/LogMeIn/bin/LogMeIn.app/Contents/Resources/logmeinserverctl" stop    
23  launchctl stop /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.logmein.logmeinserver.plist    
24  launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.logmein.logmeinserver.plist    
25  launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.logmein.LMILaunchAgentFixer.plist    
26  launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.logmein.logmeingui.plist    
27  launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.logmein.logmeinguiagent.plist    
28  rm -rf /Library/LaunchAgents/com.logmein.LMILaunchAgentFixer.plist    
29  rm -rf /Library/LaunchAgents/com.logmein.logmeingui.plist    
30  rm -rf /Library/LaunchAgents/com.logmein.logmeinguiagent.plist    
31  rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.logmein.logmeinserver.plist    
32  rm -rf "/Library/Application Support/LogMeIn/"    
33  rm -rf /Library/Logs/LogMeIn/    
34  rm -rf /Library/Receipts/LogMeIn\ Server\ Installer.pkg/    
35  rm -rf /Library/Receipts/LogMeIn\ Installer.pkg/    
36  rm -rf /Library/Printers/LogMeIn    
37  rm -rf /usr/libexec/cups/backend/LogMeInBackend    
38  rm -rf /usr/libexec/cups/filter/LogMeInFilter    
39  rm -rf /usr/libexec/cups/filter/commandtoLogMeIn    
40  rm -rf "/Applications/LogMeIn/LogMeInUninstaller.app"    
41  rm -rf "/Applications/LogMeIn/StartLogMeIn.app"    
42  rm -rf "/Applications/LogMeIn/Toolkit.app"    
43  if [ -e "/Applications/LogMeIn/LogMeInPluginUninstaller.app" ]; 
    then echo not removing LogMeIn directory; else rm -rf "/Applications/LogMeIn/"; fi  
44  rm -rf "/Library/Receipts/LogMeIn Installer.pkg"     
45  rm -rf "/Library/Receipts/logmein.pkg"     
46  rm -rf "/private/var/db/receipts/com.logmein.logmeinserverinstaller.bom"    
47  rm -rf "/private/var/db/receipts/com.logmein.logmeinserverinstaller.plist"   
48  dscl . -delete /users/LogMeInRemoteUser    
49  killall LMILaunchAgentFixer
```

I then go in and look for this logmein, but other than the uninstaller, it doesn't exist. The files show an older timestamp from about March, but still just making me nervous..

I check more history as su and find:

```
5  sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /etc/hosts            
6  stty -onlcr -echo echonl
7  /usr/bin/atos -p "1" -printHeader 
8  /usr/bin/atos -p "10" -printHeader 
9  /usr/bin/atos -p "11" -printHeader     
10  /usr/bin/atos -p "12" -printHeader     
11  /usr/bin/atos -p "13" -printHeader     
12  /usr/bin/atos -p "14" -printHeader     
13  /usr/bin/atos -p "15" -printHeader     
14  /usr/bin/atos -p "16" -printHeader     
15  /usr/bin/atos -p "17" -printHeader     
16  /usr/bin/atos -p "18" -printHeader     
17  /usr/bin/atos -p "19" -printHeader     
18  /usr/bin/atos -p "21" -printHeader     
19  /usr/bin/atos -p "24" -printHeader     
20  /usr/bin/atos -p "25" -printHeader     
21  /usr/bin/atos -p "27" -printHeader     
22  /usr/bin/atos -p "29" -printHeader     
23  /usr/bin/atos -p "30" -printHeader     
24  /usr/bin/atos -p "33" -printHeader     
25  /usr/bin/atos -p "35" -printHeader     
26  /usr/bin/atos -p "39" -printHeader     
27  /usr/bin/atos -p "40" -printHeader     
28  /usr/bin/atos -p "42" -printHeader     
29  /usr/bin/atos -p "44" -printHeader     
30  /usr/bin/atos -p "46" -printHeader     
31  /usr/bin/atos -p "48" -printHeader     
32  /usr/bin/atos -p "53" -printHeader     
33  /usr/bin/atos -p "90" -printHeader     
34  /usr/bin/atos -p "91" -printHeader     
35  /usr/bin/atos -p "96" -printHeader     
36  /usr/bin/atos -p "108" -printHeader     
37  /usr/bin/atos -p "110" -printHeader     
38  /usr/bin/atos -p "119" -printHeader     
39  /usr/bin/atos -p "122" -printHeader     
40  /usr/bin/atos -p "123" -printHeader     
41  /usr/bin/atos -p "128" -printHeader     
42  /usr/bin/atos -p "129" -printHeader     
43  /usr/bin/atos -p "131" -printHeader     
44  /usr/bin/atos -p "132" -printHeader     
45  /usr/bin/atos -p "133" -printHeader     
46  /usr/bin/atos -p "134" -printHeader     
47  /usr/bin/atos -p "139" -printHeader     
48  /usr/bin/atos -p "141" -printHeader     
49  /usr/bin/atos -p "144" -printHeader     
50  /usr/bin/atos -p "149" -printHeader     
51  /usr/bin/atos -p "154" -printHeader     
52  /usr/bin/atos -p "160" -printHeader     
53  /usr/bin/atos -p "161" -printHeader     
54  /usr/bin/atos -p "164" -printHeader     
55  /usr/bin/atos -p "197" -printHeader     
56  /usr/bin/atos -p "209" -printHeader     
57  /usr/bin/atos -p "212" -printHeader     
58  /usr/bin/atos -p "1593" -printHeader     
59  /usr/bin/atos -p "1594" -printHeader     
60  /usr/bin/atos -p "17892" -printHeader     
61  /usr/bin/atos -p "82995" -printHeader     
62  /usr/bin/atos -p "82996" -printHeader     
63  /usr/bin/atos -p "82997" -printHeader     
64  /usr/bin/atos -p "BezelUIServer" -printHeader     
65  /usr/bin/atos -p "83003" -printHeader     
66  /usr/bin/atos -p "taskgated" -printHeader     
67  /usr/bin/atos -p "83006" -printHeader     
68  /usr/bin/atos -p "83007" -printHeader     
69  /usr/bin/atos -p "83010" -printHeader     
70  /usr/bin/atos -p "com.apple.hiserv" -printHeader     
71  /usr/bin/atos -p "83014" -printHeader     
72  /usr/bin/atos -p "83015" -printHeader
```

Now maybe I was drunk when all this happened, but I am pretty sure I didn't run all of these commands.

From the first line, I can see they are looking at the hosts file so I cat that and find:

```
127.0.0.1          localhost
255.255.255.255    broadcasthost
::1                localhost
fe80::1%lo0        localhost
```

Well, I've changed my su passed and regular passed and I've erased the hosts and hope this will deter further contamination?

Or am I simply fooling myself and should just reformat my whole computer?

Comment: Sounds like someone was up to no good. Though it looks to me like this was someone with physical access to your computer.

Comment: Macs can't be hacked.

Comment: @ta.speot.is -- Ha, ha!!

Comment: log-me-in is used for remote help-desk sessions. Have you ever had anyone online work on your system? It creates a code on running that you're required to tell the person establishing the connection so they can't just connect out of the blue. Similar to how go-to-my-pc works, but with the additonal user permission check.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
stty -onlcr -echo echonl
```

and the repeated

```
/usr/bin/atos -p "XXX" -printHeader
```

comes from the stackshot program that is used to produce a stack dump for all running processes.

I found same entries in my log and got really suspicious, but after some googling around I found out that pressing <kbd>Control-Option-Command-Shift-Period</kbd> (at the same time) starts stackshot, which to my surprise actually produces these entries in `/var/root/.sh_history`.

I would appreciate if someone who knows more about OS X could explain why a shell script performing in the background does this.

For me this must have been happening when I (stupidly enough) decided to clean my keyboard while the Mac was running. :)

Answer (score 2):

It does indeed sound like someone has been messing with your Mac.  Unless you have an ssh server running to allow remote access it does sound like it is someone who had physical access to your computer.  It was probably a good idea to change your passwords, you should also make sure the computer is locked when you are not around so other people don't have access to it.  Also, keep in mind every machine is hack-able with the right skills, so your best bet is to regularly check for strange things that don't look right.  I think you did a great job catching it.