# Keyboard/mouse layout changed and weird commands in logs. Was I hacked? (OSX)

Tags: linux, command-line, security, osx-yosemite

**Edit: Looks like my colleagues had some fun. False alarm.**

My work computer is running OSX Yosemite 10.10.1. I noticed my keyboard layout was changed to Dvorak and my mouse direction reversed when logging into my work computer this morning. The computer is always locked when I leave the office. To me, it does not seem possible to add keyboards layouts or change these settings from the lock-screen.

Furthermore I found the same commands ran as in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/465141/is-my-mac-hacked-found-weird-things). There are however nothing else in root's bash history, even though I use the root account once in a while. Also, `/var/log/secure.log` does not exist in the filesystem.

I'm not a Unix expert by any sense. What other steps can I take to find out if anything was done to my computer? I don't like this situation.

Comment: Could this have been a prank? Could a colleague have accessed your Mac and changed those settings? Is your computer physically locked in a drawer or, if only software locked, could the prankster have knowledge of your password?

Comment: Turns out this actually was the case. For once, it looks like I forgot to lock my computer... Kind of embarrassing. :)